# searchbox : autosuggestion with XML

Tags: javascript, xml, search

I want to make a searchbox which has auto suggestion and searches specific tag in a XML file.
How can i realze this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by XML file. Is the XML file available at some server?

Look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its [autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/). It provides auto suggestion functionality for HTML/XHTML pages.